# Laravel 7 UI - Sessions Guard Driver - Spatie Permission Package

Tags: laravel, user-interface, authentication, permissions, laravel-permission

In short: The Sessions guard driver is rejecting my login attempts.

Before creating the Laravel UI I had already created a authentication system for my frontend using JWT as the api guard driver.

I installed the Laravel UI in order to use the Spatie Permission Package which had also been installed and had generated some extra tables.

Once the Laravel UI was installed I successfully registered a new user but was not redirected to the home screen. I attempted to log in as the new user and got a response stating that my credentials were not recognised. I then tried to log in with a user that had been previously created in the users table through the frontend registration...

Whilst it gave no error this time it still did not redirect me. I then attempted to log into the frontend app with the newly created user and was able to do so. At this point I figured there was a conflict with the tokens.

I looked in RegisterController.php and saw the following:

```
    protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

My frontend JWT auth system also uses User.php and so I had a look and saw that the password was being encrypted twice. First with Hash:: and then with bcrypt. I therefore removed the Hash encryption.

I registered successfully but again was not redirected to home. I attempted to log in again and was again unable to do so, but this time I received no error message! The registered user was now behaving in the same manner as users registered through the front end app.

I went through the code line-by-line spending hours logging out values etc. and could see that everything was being accepted and I **was** being redirected to home but the HomeController.php was then passing my credentials through the auth guard which was rejecting then and then redirecting me back to login!!

The only way I can access home is by changing the middleware in HomeController.php from 'auth' to 'guest':

```
    public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest'); // changed from 'auth'
}
```

In the Spatie documention it states the following:

> If your app uses only a single guard, but is not web (Laravel’s default, which shows “first” in the auth config file) then change the order of your  listed guards in your config/auth.php to list your primary guard as the default and as the first in the list of defined guards. While you’re editing that file, best to remove any guards you don’t use, too.

I therefore switched the guards around in config/auth.php so that api was first but it had no effect.

```
    'guards' => [

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

The frontend is using the api guard and the backend is using web but they are both using the same app/User. This I guess must be the cause of the problem but I am new to Laravel and, after hours of reading and testing, I am still struggling. What does it want that I am missing!? The password is now being accepted so it cannot be that..

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the top section of config/auth which I had missed:

```
        'defaults' => [
        'guard' =>'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
        ],
```

It wasn't that I was being rejected by the web session driver - it was that the web guard was being overwritten by the api guard in the defaults section above.

I have to specify in the routing which middleware I wanted so as to avoid the default:

```
Route::get('/home', [
'middleware' => 'auth:web', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index'])->name('home');
```

EDIT: Since auth:web was only used by a couple of controllers the better solution was to change the default guard in config/auth to web and then do Route::group with the rest that used the api guard:

```
Route::group([

    'middleware' => 'api'

], function () {

    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');
    Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh'); 
});
```